# friend calls virtual private method - what should happen

Tags: c++, inheritance, methods, virtual, friend

I had a situation where I wanted a friend class to call a private method, then I wanted to make this method virtual so derived a class's method would get called instead - then I of course realised friendship isn't inherited. So we have a situation where the virtual method means the derived class's method should be called, but this method is private so cannot be called. Which has priority?

I tested this on MSVC++ 2008 as follows

```
#include<iostream>

class Loner;

class Base
{
    friend Loner;
private:
    virtual void test(){std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
private:
    virtual void test(){std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl;}
};

class Loner
{
public:
    void test(Base *base){base->test();}
};

int main()
{
    Loner loner;
    Derived derived;
    loner.test(&derived);
}
```

The output was:

```
Derived
```

So it seems that the virtual function "wins" and gives private member access to a non friend - almost friend inheritance!

My question is, does anyone know if this is correct behaviour? When I finally get round to upgrading my compiler version or if I try on GCC might this behaviour change?

Cheers

Phil

Comment: tried this in gcc 4.8 c++11 and the behavior is the same http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3cff63c17122981

Answer (score 6):

§ 11.5/1-2 ([class.access.virt]):

> 1. The access rules (Clause 11) for a virtual function are determined by its declaration and are not affected by the rules for a function that later overrides it.
> 2. Access is checked at the call point using the type of the expression used to denote the object for which the member function is called...

So you're good to upgrade. (There's an example in the actual standard, but I left it out of the quote.)

In effect, what's going on here is that the `Base` virtual function does the despatch to  its overrides. So even though you can't call a `Derived` override statically (`Derived::member`), you can still get `Base::member` to call it for you, if you have access to `Base::member`.

Answer (score 1):

the call is being made through an object pointer with a 'static' type of `Base*` - this is the type that access checks are performed against. These access checks occur at compile time. Since `Loner` is a friend of `Base`, the compiler is fine with permitting the call to `base->test()`.

However, the dynamic type of the object that the `base` pointer points to is `Derived`.  At runtime there are no additional access checks - the call is made to the dynamic type, which is dispatch through the normal virtual call mechanism.